# Run Jest test and collect coverage from all files in a specific directory

Tags: testing, jestjs

I am using the following code to run Jest test on specific file.

```
   jest utils.spec.js --collectCoverageFrom=**/utils.js
```

If i want to test whole directory i use

```
jest someDirectory --collectCoverageFrom=**/someDirectory
```

But the code coverage does not work here why is so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add this pattern `/**/*.js`, that match all the files in all sub directories:

```
jest someDirectory --collectCoverageFrom=**/someDirectory/**/*.js
```

Comment: Although tests executed for specified directory the coverage is performed on all the available tests.