# Jest running tests by specific path

Tags: javascript, jestjs, testunit

currently I am using the standard testRegex logic to run my tests

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js",
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "/tests/.*\\.(ts|js)$"
  }
```

But I would like to split them using specific paths

```
test-client   "testRegex": "/tests/client/.*\\.(ts|js)$"
test-server   "testRegex": "/tests/server/.*\\.(ts|js)$"
```

I see that there is a, option   --runTestsByPath. but I cannot find any example of it

feedback welcome

UPDATE

I tried to add the script

```
"test-client": "jest   --runTestsByPath \"tests/client/\""
```

with a test  file : tests/client/test.spec.js

but got an error :

```
$ jest   --runTestsByPath "tests/client/"
No tests found
No files found in /Users/../myapp.
Make sure Jest's configuration does not exclude this directory.
```

Comment: here are a few examples of usage: https://github.com/search?q=--runTestsByPath&type=Code

Comment: Thanks @Paul , I tried to add it ( see my update in the question ... could not find such example ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run Jest test and collect coverage from all files in a specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44614353/run-jest-test-and-collect-coverage-from-all-files-in-a-specific-directory)

Answer (score 5):

I use the follow command and works:

```
jest "/client"
```

You can see the Jest documentation here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/22.x/cli

Answer (score 1):

### --runTestsByPath needs the leading './'

I have got this working for myself:

```
jest --runTestsByPath "./directory/testFile.js"
```

and

```
jest --runTestsByPath "./directory"
```

Note I'm on WSL1, but should be the same for most flavours of linux.

Answer (score -1):

```sh
jest someDirectory --collectCoverageFrom=**/someDirectory/**/*.js
```